# SyncFusion : syncfusion dialog does not open correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: syncfusion

I am using SyncFusion dialog box as below in one of my project.

```
<%=Html.Syncfusion().Dialog("divUpdateStatus")
                .Title("Update Status")
                .AutoOpen(false).Modal(true).Width(550).Height(370)    
        .AutoFormat(Skins.Office2007Black) 
        .Resizable(false)
%>
```

It does work fine in all the browsers except Internet Exploere(any version).
When I click on the button to open this dialog, it does open but everything is inactive.

All the buttons and textboxes on the dialog are disabled.

Not even Cross button to cancel the dialog is enabled to close the dialog.
I have to press 'ESC' to comeout of this, then again I click on button to open that, it works fine.

On the added reference of the Syncfusion dll, it shows Version: 10.204.0.56

Anyone has idea on this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Syncfusion Dialog in my application, but it is working fine in Internet Explorer for me. My application referred jquery-1.4.2 script and jquery-ui-1.8.22 script within it. Dialog is working fine with this.

I have used Syncfusion version 10.2.0.56 and use the below code to render Dialog,

```
   <code>
       <div id="divUpdateStatus" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <%=Html.Label("lbl", "UserName") %>
        <%=Html.TextBox("text")%><br /><br />
        <%=Html.Label("lbl2", "Password")%>
        <%=Html.TextBox("text")%><br /><br />
        <%=Html.Syncfusion().Button("btn").Text("Submit")%>
      </div>

        <%=Html.Syncfusion().Dialog("divUpdateStatus").Title("UpdateStatus").AutoOpen(false).Modal(true).Width(550).Height(370).AutoFormat(Skins.Office2007Black).Resizable(false) %>

        <%=Html.Syncfusion().Button("button").ClientSideOnClick("onclick").Text("Click to open the dialog")%>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function onclick(sender, args) {
       $("#divUpdateStatus").dialog("open");
     }
   </script>

 </code>
```

Share more details or issue reproducible steps in detail and we will see what’s wrong with your code.

Regards,